# CarouselView - prev/next element visible [Xamarin Forms]

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, carousel

Is it possible to show previous and next element in `CarouselView` control in `Xamarin Forms`? I mean stuff like that:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/88qle.jpg

Additionally, i want to show name of element above.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to show 3 item at a time but you can refer this link and use CarouselView nuget package for carousel view

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/69120/carouselview-2-3-0-pre2